# Why can't i create a neo4j relationship with spring data for neo?

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

i'm fairly new to spring data for neo (though i have experience with neo4j itself). i tried following the 'official' guide on spring data for neo, specifically the chapter on [creating relationships](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-neo4j/current/reference/html/#creating_relationships).

But it seems i cannot get it to work. Spring is giving me an

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: This index (Index[__rel_types__,Relationship]) has been marked as deleted in this transaction`

Let me stress, that i am NOT removing any nodes or relationships. These are the relevant classes of my domain model:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {

    @GraphId
    private Long nodeid;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String uuid;
    ....


}

@NodeEntity
public class Website {

    @GraphId
    private Long nodeid;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String uuid;

    ....

}

@RelationshipEntity(type = RelTypes.REL_USER_INTERESTED_IN)
public class UserInterest {

    @GraphId
    private Long nodeid;

    @StartNode
    private User user;

    @EndNode
    private Website site;
    ...

}
```

And this is my basic test which i can't get to turn green ..
(note that i omitted large portions of the code, the basic setup of the spring context etc. is working fine)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@Transactional
public class BaseTest {

    @Autowired
    protected Neo4jTemplate template;
    @Autowired
    protected GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService;

    protected Transaction tx;

    @Configuration
    @EnableNeo4jRepositories
    static class TestConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {
        TestConfig() throws ClassNotFoundException {
            setBasePackage("me.bcfh.model");
        }

        @Bean
        GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
            return new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();
        }

    }

    public void before() {
        // provide implementation if necessary
    }

    public void after() {
        // provide implementation if necessary

    }

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        Neo4jHelper.cleanDb(graphDatabaseService, false);
        before();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        after();
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.success();
            tx.close();
            tx = null;
        }
    }
}
public class BasicGraphTest extends BaseTest {

    User user;
    Website website;
    UserInterest interest;

    @Override
    public void before() {
        user = new User();
        website = new Website();
        website = template.save(website);
        user = template.save(user);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void dbShouldContainData() throws Exception {
        UserInterest interest = new UserInterest();
        interest.setSite(website);
        interest.setUser(user);
        template.save(interest);

        // some assertions 
        ... 
    }
}
```

The IllegalStateException is being thrown when I try persisting the UserInterest instance, which I do not understand because I am not removing anything anywhere.

The ways to create a relationship mentioned in the spring guide did not work for me either, here I got the same exception ..

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

I am using Spring Version 4.1.4.RELEASE and Spring Data For Neo Version 3.2.1.RELEASE. Neo4j has version 2.1.6

Note: I also tried copying the domain model classes from the [cineasts](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/tree/master/spring-data-neo4j-examples/cineasts) example into my project and borrowed a few lines of the DomainTest class but this too gives me the IllegalStateException, maybe there is something wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting your IllegalStateException because you are calling cleanDb in your setup method.

You may not need to clean the database.  Since your tests are makred @Transactional anything you do in your tests gets rolled back at the end of the test.

Looks like the transaction is trying to rollback and can't find the relationship it expects.

Comment: You are actually right. Looking at it now, your explaination makes an aweful lot of sense to me (it was really late last night ..) Also I don't even need to call cleanDb as this is an impermanent neo4j db which will get discarded after the test anyway. 

Test is green, relationship exists, problem solved.
Thanks a lot =)